# Why is the day of the week missing?

Tags: gnome, 20.04, calendar

For several days now, the day of the week has not been displayed on the time sub-menu, as shown in the screenshot. I use Ubuntu 20.04 with Gnome.

[image: Calendar has a space instead of weekday]

How can I fix this?

Comment: Similar issue with additional workarounds: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1333525/day-name-not-showing-in-calendar

Answer (score 4):

It's probably a bug in [this update](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-shell/3.36.7-0ubuntu0.20.04.1), which landed in `focal-updates` on 2021-03-25.

Please feel free to file a bug report:

```
ubuntu-bug gnome-shell
```

Answer (score 1):

I recently moved to 20.04 and had the same issue.  One workaround I found was to open the Settings, disable auto update of the date if enabled, manually move the date a day forward or back in Settings, then while keeping the Settings open, open the top bar calendar and you should see the day-of-week appear.  At that point just set the date back to the correct date or auto update in Settings and close.  I couldn't tell you why this works though.

Answer (score 0):

Install GNOME Tweaks from the Ubuntu Software Centre and set the Top Bar to show Weekday.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your help but please, read the question carefully, this solution desn't solve my problem.

Comment: this indeed changes what is in the top bar, not what is in the submenu.

Comment: @vanadium curious then that my implementation of Tweaks on a standard vanilla 20.04.2 LTS shows the day in the submenu correctly.

Comment: Even with "weekday" disabled in this Tweaks setting, the weekday remains in the submenu. If this is a bug, then you are not necessarily affected by it as well.