# No day in week inside calendar menu

Tags: calendar

As you can see below, calendar applet does not show day in week, which I remember was not the case before. Is this a glitch or did I somehow manage to disable it somewhere in settings?

[image]

Comment: Look here: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1328674/why-the-day-of-the-week-is-missing

Comment: That is the exact same issue as mine, but the answers there do not solve my issue, I am afraid.

Comment: hakan, unfortunately I think [Gunnar Hjalmarsson's answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1328681/527764) is the best you are going to get - this is a bug, which should be reported against the `gnome-shell` package on Launchpad - there is no solution until it gets fixed by developers (hopefully soon), so your question really is a duplicate of that one, in my view.

Comment: I guess so. Yoles, the asker of the original question seems to have already created a bug report. I am currently following the bug report, and will post an answer to his question once this issue gets fixed. Thanks!