# Day Name Not Showing in Calendar

Tags: gnome, themes, calendar

I just installed Ubuntu 20.04 and after configuring everything on GNOME Shell and extensions, I noticed that the name of the current day is not displayed above the date in the calendar section as shown in the picture below.

[image]

However, if I change the shell theme in GNOME Tweaks, the day name appears.

[image]

It doesn't matter which theme I choose. Even choosing the theme on the first picture will do the magic.
Is there any way to fix this?

Comment: This seems to be the same issue as this: https://askubuntu.com/q/1328674/1157519 And there you have the [community consensus answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1329534/no-day-in-week-inside-calendar-menu#comment2267095_1329534) that it's a bug introduced in the most recent gnome-shell update. Normally we would suggest that this is a duplicate of that question, but this time **your question seems to be superior**, because you have found a workaround that may be a better alternative than: "just wait"...

Comment: Perhaps you could add an answer there, suggesting the theme change as a workaround...

Comment: I can't comment any of those questions due to a lack of reputation :/ And I rather not answer as this is just a workaround that will be undone when you log out or reboot.

Comment: I also noticed that chaging the font of the system will show the day name. I think there is some issue with the render of the calendar section size.

Answer (score 1):

I realized that not only by changing the theme the day name will appear again, but also by resizing the system font or rescaling the screen. Then, one permanent solution is to create a script that runs on startup, just like this one:

```
#!/bin/bash
set -eu
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.interface text-scaling-factor 2
sleep 10s
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.interface text-scaling-factor 1
```

I put 10 secs because in my laptop with less than that the script won't work. You can change that value according to your system.

Comment: I tried `gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.interface font-name "Ubuntu 12"` and then back to the Ubuntu factory original "Ubuntu 11"; also brings back the day name. (I tried first to just re-affirm the already existing value (Ubuntu 11), hoping that the trick with the sleep could be avoided, but no, that alone does not trigger any change. The value indeed has to be changed in order to bring the day back.)

Comment: I vote that you earn any or each of the `investigative`, `out-of-the-box-thinker`, `tweaker`, `creative-tinkerer`, and `perseverant` badges :)